# Which plane do Spectators originate from?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, planes

The description of [Spectators](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-b#Spectator) on page 30 of the *Monster Manual* begins:

> A spectator is a lesser beholder that is summoned from another plane of existence by a magical ritual

Which plane do they originally come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description of spectators on page 112 of [*Monster Manual II* for AD&D 1st edition](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/17005/Monster-Manual-II-1e) says:

> Spectators are summoned from Nirvana [...]

The description references the spectator returning to Nirvana several more times in the text (e.g. if it is not commanded to guard a treasure, can no longer fulfill this duty, or is released from service).

Nirvana is another name for [Mechanus](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Mechanus). (The plane was simply called "Nirvana" in 1e, but was referred to as "Mechanus" in 2e; from 3e onwards, its full name was stated to be "the Clockwork Nirvana of Mechanus".)

Comment: Turns out I should search before I post questions, but leaving this here for posterity.

Comment: Nirvana doesn't appear to be a plane on the 5e wheel. The only mention of the word is in "The clockwork nirvana of Mechanus" which I don't think refers to the same thing.

Comment: @Someone_Evil it was called Nirvana in 1e, Mechanus in 2e and both from 3e onward. Maybe the Spectator didn’t get the memo?

Comment: Haha it never occurred to me to ensure Nirvana was an actual plane in 5e!

Comment: The [FR wiki article on Mechanus](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Mechanus) seems to confirm this, with a citation by the alternate name pointing to the 3e *Manual of the Planes*: "The Clockwork Nirvana of Mechanus, sometimes called Nirvana,[10] [...]" I've edited the answer to elaborate on this a bit, per the info in the comments.

Comment: @DaleM The AD&D 2nd Edition Monstrous Manual states that spectators are summoned from Nirvana.