# What range is used to determine the target of the attack made by the creature affected by a Spectator's Confusion Ray?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, attack, targeting

The [Spectator](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/spectator) has an Eye Ray option, Confusion Ray, that says:

> [The target] uses its action to make a melee or ranged attack against a randomly determined creature within range.

Unlike the spell [Confusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/confusion) which limits the attack to melee attacks, the Spectator's victim can be compelled to make a ranged attack.

When determining the random target, are creatures that are outside of the weapon's normal range but within the weapon's long range included?

For a specific example, say a Rogue with a light crossbow is hit by the ray and fails their save. On their turn, there are three allies within 80 feet, and the Spectator is 90 feet away. Is there a chance that the Rogue randomly targets the Spectator?

Comment: My question was prompted by looking at [Which plane do Spectators originate from?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171285/60913)

Comment: This makes me realise that a spectator in a town could be devastating when confusing people into attacking the townsfolk! Take a wizards items at your peril.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, there is no limit listed. In 5e, [range](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) encompasses both normal and long range. That means you should select from all targets within normal range and long range.

In your example, a light crossbow has a range of 320 feet, so the Spectator who is only 90ft away can be targeted.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **the longest range of your currently equipped weapon. Or unarmed attack.**

In your example, 90 ft is within light crossbow range, so they are 'in range' and should be included in the random creature pool.

**However, the interpretation is ultimately up to the DM**. The description is short and leaves much open to interpretation. The intent of the spell is to remove some of player agency, so rather than worrying who is included in the random pool, just pick one randomly from creatures nearby.